# Console response json

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropbox, dropbox-api

Hi sorry for this simple question I just need to call the `.tag` in my json response in my dropbox api and i cant called the `.tag` is always says `undefined`

This is the json response in my dropbox api

```
.tag:"folder"
id:"id:dEOW7ElDHUgAAAAAAAAAJg"
name:"Sample Folder"
path_display:"/Sample Folder"
path_lower:"/sample folder"
```

Comment: It doesn't look like JSON.

Comment: did you try `data[".tag"]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have this

```
".tag":"folder"
```

and

```
object[".tag"]
```